# How to call the managebean method from panel form button in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Command Button is not working in my xhtml page when i am clicking on button its not calling Save method of CalendarController but handleSelectData method working fine.  so please tell me where i am wrong.
xhtml file

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<p:dialog id="eventdailog" width="425px" height="320px"
    header=" Create Event" widgetVar="dlg" focus="event"
    showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">
    <h:form id="createevent">
        <p>
            <p:commandLink
                value="Important:Learn about Event Management features"
                style="text-decoration:none" />
        </p>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="event">
        <p:tabView>

            <p:tab id="Event1" title="Event">

                <h:form id="eventtab">
                    <h:outputLabel for="event" />
                    <p:inputText id="event" label="Description" rendered="true" />
                    <p:watermark for="event" value="Please add description" />

                    <h:outputLabel for="date" />
                    <p:calendar value="#{calendar.date}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
                        id="date" showOn="button" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{calendar.date}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" />
                    </h:outputText>
                    <p:autoComplete id="autoComp"
                        value="#{autocompleteBeanController.selectedUserProfiles}"
                        completeMethod="#{autocompleteBeanController.completeUserProfile}"
                        var="auto" itemLabel="#{auto.displayName}" itemValue="#{auto}"
                        converter="#{userAutocompleteConverter}" forceSelection="true"
                        required="true" rerequiredMessage="Send to is required"
                        label="Send to" minQueryLength="1" maxResults="5" multiple="true">

                        <p:ajax event="itemUnselect"
                            listener="#{autocompleteBeanController.handleUnselect}" />
                        <p:column>
                            <p:graphicImage value="#{auto.imagePath}" width="30" height="20" />
                                        #{auto.displayName}
                                    </p:column>

                    </p:autoComplete>
                    <p:watermark for="autoComp" value="Send to.."
                        onclick="PrimeFaces.cleanWatermarks();"
                        oncomplete="PrimeFaces.showWatermarks();" />
                    <br />

                    <p:commandButton id="save" value="Create"
                        actionListner="#{calendarController.save}"
                        onclick="dlg.hide();return false" />

                </h:form>
            </p:tab>
```

CalendarController.java

```java
@Named
@Scope("session")
public class CalendarController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6221780314938096482L;
    private Date date;
    @Inject
    private AutocompleteBeanController autocompletebean;

    @Inject
    private EventService eventService;

    @Inject
    private ManagedLoginBean login;

    public ManagedLoginBean getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(ManagedLoginBean login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public EventService getEventService() {
        return eventService;
    }

    public void setEventService(EventService eventService) {
        this.eventService = eventService;
    }

    public AutocompleteBeanController getAutocompletebean() {
        return autocompletebean;
    }

    public void setAutocompletebean(AutocompleteBeanController autocompletebean) {
        this.autocompletebean = autocompletebean;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void handleDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dlg.show();");

    }

    public void save(ActionEvent event) {
        EventDTO eventDto = new EventDTO();
        eventDto.setEventUserDto(PaatashaalaUtil.getUserProfileDTO(login));
        int status = eventService.createEvent(eventDto);
        FacesMessage msg = null;
        if (status == 1) {
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event Update",
                    null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("event", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you entered any value in the `autoComplete`? Are there any validation errors? How are you sure that the method is not called? Is there even no request sent or is just the method not called?

Comment: i debug my code its not calling save method.

Comment: For performing pure business, use `action` instead of `actionListener`. Listeners are considered auxiliary tools.

Comment: @XtremeBiker action also not workng.

Comment: Did you remove the arguments for your `save` method when switching to `action`? Also be sure your `CalendarController` bean is built.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I removed the argument from save method but still is not working.

Comment: @user3319178 - the most probable cause for an action not being executed is a conversion/validation failure. Either add a `<p:messages/>` component to your page or look in your browser's javascript console's network tab to look out for silent conversion errors

Comment: @kolossus I have put <p:messages> but still isn't working.

Comment: @kolossus sorry guys i got my error i made mistake on p:calendar value =#{calendar.date} is not there and how find it just put in button ajax="false" then i got the error.That's the solution.

Comment: @XtremeBiker sorry guys i got my error i made mistake on p:calendar value =#{calendar.date} is not there and how find it just put in button ajax="false" then i got the error.That's the solution

Comment: Just a tip: before posting a question try to issolate the problem by yourself. Remove irrelevant parts of the code as much as possible, till you've got the simplest piece of code which can reproduce the issue. For people answering it's also a help if you post something that can be copy-paste and ran. Look at the [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) guide for further info ;-)

Comment: @XtremeBiker ok thanks for the wonderful tips. Next time i keep this tips in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The correct attribute for `p:commandButton` is `actionListener` and not `actionlistener`

Comment: in my code <p:commandButton id="save" value="Create"
       actionListener="#{calendarController.save}"
       onclick="dlg.hide();return false" />

Comment: The code looks fine. How are you determining that the method isn't called ?

Comment: sorry guys i got my error i made mistake on p:calendar value =#{calendar.date} is not there and how find it just put in button ajax="false" then i got the error.That's the solution.